# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. Any fix?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, membership, password-recovery

I'm trying to have a recovery password page in my website, but there's an error every time: "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

I enter the username, clicking submit. It takes me to the secret question and answer page, I type the answer and clicking submit. Then, it shows me the error about the email. Is there a fix for it?

This is my page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageTest.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="forgotpass.aspx.cs" Inherits="forgotpass" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<br />
<center><b>
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server" 
        TextLayout="TextOnTop" 
        UserNameInstructionText="הכנס את שם המשתמש שלך כדי לקבל את סיסמתך" 
        UserNameLabelText="שם משתמש:" UserNameTitleText="שכחת את סיסמתך?">
        <UserNameTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    שכחת את סיסמתך?</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    הכנס את שם המשתמש שלך כדי לקבל את סיסמתך</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">שם משתמש:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" CommandName="Submit" Text="אפס סיסמא" 
                                        ValidationGroup="PasswordRecovery1" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </UserNameTemplate>
    </asp:PasswordRecovery>
</b></center>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the correct From in the MailDefinition of your control. Example:

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery ID="PasswordRecovery1" runat="server">
     <MailDefinition From="...@gmail.com" Subject="ResetPassword"
      Priority="High"/>
</asp:PasswordRecovery>
```

Either this way or from your code-behind.

Plus you need to make sure that the EmailAddress returned by your Membership provider is a valid one.

Also, make sure that your application is correctly configured to send email messages. Check the web.config file, section system.net -> mailSettings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="host.domain.com" userName="..." password="..." />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You can remove the `userName` and `password` if your SMTP server accepts unauthorized connections from your IP address.

As a quick fix you can attach to the SendingMail event of the control (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.sendingmail(v=vs.110).aspx) and show a nice error message and cancel the message using:

```
e.Cancel = true; // where e is the MailMessageEventHandler
```

But if all validations are in place and all settings OK you should not have this scenario anyway.

Comment: I modified the <asp:PasswordRecovery> and added the <MailDefinition> that you gave me with my own changes. Now it gives me this error: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 66.96.162.96:25"

Comment: You need to have a STMP server to send email messages. I have updated my answer. Please check the new info about the web.config configuration.

Comment: If you have it and you receive the "A connection attempt failed ..." error then it means that you cannot connect to your SMTP server. Try testing the connection with telnet or another tool... Can you send other messages from your app?

Comment: Nevermind, port was 587, not 25. It works perfectly now!
Another minor question, is there a way to make the email send a link to the website and the user will enter a new password there instead of generating weird passwords and send them to the user's email?

Comment: Sure! As I mentioned in the answer, you should attach to the SendingMail event and override the message body there (generate and add a personalised link to a "change password page", etc...).